# Panel which stacks child elements horizontally, fitting them into the available size

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, panel

I'm looking for some layout panel for WPF which "stacks" its children horizontally, but fits them all into the panel, i.e. not like `StackPanel` which just keeps on adding them with their full width.

So for example, this magical panel is 1000 points wide. I add a child element to it, which gets the full 1000 point width. I add another one and the two children get 500 points each. I add yet another one and the three children now get 333.33333... point width. Et cetera.

Comment: could you clarify a little bit?

Comment: @qntmfred: Clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" />
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx), settings it's property - Rows to 1. This panel arranges childs in cell's of equal sizes.